How to implement HATEOAS in NestJS
Has anyone built a RESTful API with HATEOAS (Level 3 maturity) in NestJS? Are there any libraries or tools to help with this?
If implementing it manually, would you create a specific DTO (Data Transfer Object) for each response? Or would you use a more general structure like this:
{
  "data": T,
  "links": Link[]
}

How would you decide which links to include for each resource? Where would this configuration be set?
